# Conditional column extraction

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Let $A$ be the following matrix

```
A = {{1, 0, 9}, {5, 0, 6}, {4, 1, 9}, {7, 0, 11}, {8, 1, 2}}
```

and let $B$ be the matrix that comes from $A$ with

```
B = A[[All, {1, 3}]]
```

How can I implement the condition that $B$ is made only out of $A$'s rows that contain a zero?

(i.e. how can I get

```
B = {{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}
```

instead of

```
B = {{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {4, 9}, {7, 11}, {8, 2}}
```

? )

Comment: `Pick[A[[All,{1,3}]],Times@@@A,0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way out of 100 ways I am sure :)

```
Select[A, MemberQ[#, 0] &][[All, {1, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could just delete the zeros

```
DeleteCases[Select[A, MemberQ[#, 0] &], 0, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

If column 2 is binary, you can use

```
Pick[A[[All, {1, 3}]], A[[All, 2]], 0] (* or *)

Extract[A, Position[A[[All, 2]], 0], #[[{1, 3}]] &] (* or *)

A[[PositionIndex[A[[All, 2]]]@0, {1, 3}]]
```

to get

> ```
> {{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}
> ```

In general, you can wrap column 2 with `Unitize`:

```
Pick[A[[All, {1, 3}]], Unitize @ A[[All, 2]], 0]

Extract[A, Position[Unitize @ A[[All, 2]], 0], #[[{1, 3}]] &]

A[[PositionIndex[Unitize[A[[All, 2]]]]@0, {1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a *thing* for `Cases` lately:

```
Cases[A,{PatternSequence[a_,0,b_]}:>{a,b}]

(* {{1,9},{5,6},{7,11}} *)
```

Nasser accurately points out that this is equivalent (& much more apt for code-golfing!):

```
Cases[A,{a_,0,b_}:>{a,b}]
```

Comment: nice, yes cases is powerful. But in this case, you could just do `Cases[A,{a_,0,b_}:>{a,b}]` Ok, so we have like 10 ways shown so far. 90 more ways to do this is left :)

Comment: Thanks this is true. I'll update it! I like pattern-matching too much maybe hah!

Answer (score 2):

```
Query[All, If[#[[2]] == 0, #[[{1, 3}]], Nothing] &] @ A
```

{{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

```
If[#2 == 0, {#1, #3}, Nothing] & @@@ list
```

{{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 0, 9}, {5, 0, 6}, {4, 1, 9}, {7, 0, 11}, {8, 1, 2}};
```

Position-related solutions

```
p = Position[list, 0]
```

{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 2}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
Cases[{_, _}] @ ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

Using `Delete`

```
Cases[{_, _}] @ Delete[p] @ list
```

{{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

Using `Extract`

```
Extract[list, p /. {a_, _} :> {a, {1, -1}}]
```

{{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 0, 9}, {5, 0, 6}, {4, 1, 9}, {7, 0, 11}, {8, 1, 2}};

SequenceCases[list, {{a_, 0, b_}} :> {a, b}]

DeleteCases[{_, Except[0], _}][list] // #[[All, {1, 3}]] &

list /. {a_, 0, b_} :> {a, b} // Select[Length@# == 2 &]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 0, 9}, {5, 0, 6}, {4, 1, 9}, {7, 0, 11}, {8, 1, 2}};
```

---

Another way using `AnyTrue`, `Pick` and `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[Pick[#, AnyTrue[#, # == 0 &] & /@ #], 0, 2] &@list
```

*Result*:

> {{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}

Or using `SequenceReplace`:

```
Cases[{_, _}]@SequenceReplace[list, {{a___, 0, b___}} :> {a, b}]
```

*Result*:

> {{1, 9}, {5, 6}, {7, 11}}